# Apache config: HTML injection to all subdomains

Tags: html, apache, subdomain

I need to all subdomains in my Apache webserver inject HTML code to top of the site. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend a file in the main `.htaccess` by using :

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/utilities.php"
```

And from this file you can generate some HTML / CSS / JS and echo it.

Be carefull by using this because this will act like a `require`, so if the path is not valid a fatal error will be thrown.